# Runtime 'Div' making in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to make a div element in JavaScript and place a google chart on it.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)

function drawChart() {
div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 1;
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.top = 291;
div.style.left = 439;
div.style.width = 500;
div.style.height = 500;
document.body.appendChild(div);
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
 ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
 ['Work',     1],
 ['Eat',      2],
 ['Commute',  2],
 ['Watch TV', 2],
 ['Sleep',    2]
]);
var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
 'width':300,
 'height':300};
var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(1));
pieChart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Nothing shows up... but if I manually make a div in body with `<div>` tag... and give its id here, that works. Am I doing something wrong with new div creation or what?

Comment: Should this `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)` not be after the function being defined? ie in the end of that script?

Answer (score 2):

ID's are strings, change

```
div.id = 1;
```

to

```
div.id = 'MyElement';
```

and

```
var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('MyElement'));
```

or just use the reference from the variable

```
var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(div);
```

and so are styles btw :

```
div.style.top = '291px';
```

Comment: Already done both.. still nothing shows up. and who said ids are string?? they can be integers too.

Comment: Using an integer would probably work in most browsers, but no, ID's ***are*** strings, but in HTML5 they can start with a number, but it's still a string, so the proper way would be `element.id = '1';` note the quotes.

Comment: @AbdulJabbar: `<div id=1></div>` --> `var x = document.getElementById(1);` --> `console.log(typeof x.id);` === `string` --> [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j46FX/)

Comment: And yes, setting any style in plain JS is also done with strings, so it is required that you use a string and the unit, as in `'444px'`